# Find $dy/dx$ of $y=\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $y=\sin^{-1}\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

So, I took $\sin$ on both sides of the equation and found out the derivative which looks like:
$\cos y\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac2{1+x^2}$

The answer on my textbook is: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac2{1+x^2}$,where it assumed $x=\tan \theta$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. We would like to help, but ... First of all, we cannot make sense of your expression. Do you mean $\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$? It looks to me like you do not know how to differentiate $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ correctly. The rest of your comment is unintelligible. Please make the effort to learn MathJax if you're going to participate in this site.

Comment: when you write 2/1 that equals 2, right? So why write it that way?

Comment: P.S. You should have learned many years ago that parentheses are essential to make sense of mathematical expressions. As you typed it, inside the parentheses you have $2x/1 + x^2 = 2x + x^2$, but surely you intended $2x/(1+x^2)$. Parentheses are esssential. Using the fraction notation \frac{}{} is far better.

Comment: Hint: $y=2\arctan x$.

Answer (score 4):

First, the answer in your textbook is incorrect.

If $y=\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{2}{1+x^2}\operatorname{sgn}(1-x^2)$

Here is a graph of $\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$. Notice that the graph is decreasing for $|x|>1$ and increasing for $|x|<1$.

[image: Graph of y]

To understand how to find the derivative consider this triangle diagram of $y=\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$.

[image: Triangle diagram of arcsine]

From the relationship of the sides we see that $\cos(y)=\dfrac{\,| 1-x^2|\,}{1+x^2}$

Now, when we find that

$$ \cos(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2} $$

we find that

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=&\frac{2(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}\cdot\frac{1+x^2}{\,|1-x^2|\,}\\
&=&\frac{2}{1+x^2}\cdot\frac{1-x^2}{\,|1-x^2|\,}\\
&=&\frac{2}{1+x^2}\operatorname{sgn}(1-x^2)
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Hint : use [tangent half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula); $\sin(2\theta)=\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}$, where $x=\tan(\theta)$. Then conclude by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) (i.e. $\dfrac{dy}{d\theta}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}\cdot\dfrac{dx}{d\theta}$).

**Erratum** : thanks to the rigourousness of John Wayland Bales. My above hint is incorrect (incomplete) due to ignoring the domaine of definition of $sin^{-1}$. Taking that into account
$$sin^{-1}(sin(2\theta))=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}2\theta,\quad \text{if } \theta\in[\dfrac{\pi}{4},-\dfrac{\pi}{4}]\\
-(2\theta\pm \pi),~\text{otherwise}.\end{array}
\right.$$
Translating those conditions on $\theta$ to $x$, they are equivalent to the sign of $1-x^2$, as showed by [Brian's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4520066/778973).

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin{\left(y\right)}=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin{\left(y\right)}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$$

$$\cos{\left(y\right)}\frac{dy}{dx}=2x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(2x\right)$$

$$\cos{\left(y\right)}\frac{dy}{dx}=2x\left(-\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(1+x^2\right)+\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\left(2\right)$$

$$\cos{\left(y\right)}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\left(2x\right)+\frac{2}{1+x^2}$$

$$\cos{\left(y\right)}\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{4x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}+\frac{2}{1+x^2}$$

$$\cos{\left(y\right)}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-4x^2+2\left(1+x^2\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}$$

$$\cos{\left(y\right)}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}$$

But we know (at least for $-90^{\circ}\leq y\leq 90^{\circ}$) that $\cos{\left(y\right)} = \sqrt{1-\sin^2{\left(y\right)}}=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)^2}$. Putting this in the main equation gives

$$\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{\left(1+x^2\right)^2-\left(2x\right)^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}}$$

If we assume that $-1\leq x\leq1$ then $\sqrt{\frac{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}}=\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}$. Therefore the above equation becomes

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2-2x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}\cdot \left(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}\right)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2\left(1-x^2\right)\left(1+x^2\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^2\left(1-x^2\right)}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Do *not* ever use degrees when you’re doing calculus with trig functions. The variables must be in radians or else the derivative formulas must be changed!

Comment: I have not used degrees in any of my expressions. I only talked about an identity that is valid in a given range, and i mentioned the range in degrees. As long as i am not using degrees in the actual expressions there is no need for any of the formulas to be changed!